# LayeredDigraphLayout with node location?

Tags: gojs

I want the diagram with LayeredDigraphLayout and able to position the nodes wherever I want. is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, set **Layout.isInitial** to true. Read more about the issues at https://gojs.net/latest/intro/layouts.html#LayoutInvalidation